# NodeJs, MongoDb - Why is my code duplicating documents instead of updating them?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to find an existing document in MongoDB by its _id. Everything works except trying to edit existing just creates a new document with a new _id instead of updating the current. It seems that it skips **if (this._id) {** in the model file. Very frustrated because I can see the issue but cannot find a fix. Thanks in advance!

plant.js controller:

```
exports.getEditPlant = (req, res, next) => {
    const editMode = req.query.edit;
    if (!editMode) {
        console.log('Not Edit Mode');
    }
    const dbId = req.params._id;
    Plant.findById(dbId)
    .then(plant => {
        if (!plant) {
            console.log('Err');
            res.redirect('back');
        }
        res.render('account/edit-plant', {
            pageTitle: 'Edit Plant',
            path: '/account',
            plant: plant,
            edit: editMode
        });
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
};

exports.postEditPlant = (req, res, next) => {
    const updatedName = req.body.common_name;
    const scientific_name = req.body.scientific_name;
    const updatedImg = req.body.image_url;
    const slug = req.body.slug;

    const updatedPlant = new Plant(updatedName, scientific_name, updatedImg, slug, new ObjectId(id));
    updatedPlant.addMyPlant()
    .then(plant => {
        res.redirect('home');
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    })
};
```

plant.js model:

```
const mongodb = require('mongodb');
const getDB = require('../util/database').getDB;

module.exports = class Plant {
    constructor(common_name, scientific_name, image_url, slug, id) {
        this.common_name = common_name;
        this.scientific_name = scientific_name;
        this.image_url = image_url;
        this.slug = slug;
        this._id = id;
    }
    addMyPlant() {
        const db = getDB();
        let dbOp;
        if (this._id) {
            dbOp = db
            .collection('myplants')
            .updateOne({ _id: new mongodb.ObjectId(this._id) }, { $set: this });
        } else {
            dbOp = db.collection('myplants').insertOne(this);
        }
        return dbOp
        .then(result => {
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
    static getMyPlants() {
        const db = getDB();
        return db.collection('myplants')
        .find().toArray()
        .then(plants => {
            return plants;
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
    static findById(dbId) {
        const db = getDB();
        return db
          .collection('myplants')
          .find({ _id: new mongodb.ObjectId(dbId) })
          .next()
          .then(plant => {
            return plant;
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
          });
    }
}
```

Comment: try to change this line .updateOne({ _id: new mongodb.ObjectId(this._id) }, { $set: this }); to this: db.collection_name.updateOne({"_id" : record["_id"]}, new_data}. Do not pass the $set to it. Clear?

Comment: still adding duplicate instead of updating by _id

Comment: Try with upsert operator
            .updateOne({ _id: new mongodb.ObjectId(this._id) }, { $set: this },{upsert:true);

Comment: @SarahMartin have you managed to sort this out?

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the known `_id` to the `ObjectID` outside of the query.
In your code, you instantiate a new ObjectID inside your query but the value you passed in is not found.

This is a simplified version of your class with tests:

```
const mongodb =  require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb";

class Plant {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    // this method pulls all the records for me to test results
    getAll() {
        mongodb.connect(url, { useUnifiedTopology: true }, (err, db) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            var dbo = db.db("mydb");

            dbo.collection("plants").find({}).toArray(function (err, result) {
                if (err) console.log(err);
                console.log(result);
                db.close();
            });

        })
    }

    // update single record
    updateMyPlant() {
        mongodb.connect(url, { useUnifiedTopology: true }, (err, db) => {
            if (err) console.log(err);
            console.log("Mongo connected...");

            const dbo = db.db("mydb");

            // if you know the _id
            // instantiate a variable outside your query
            // now const id is the same as the _id you wants to query
            const id = ObjectID("5fd8a1100617b03d8c737da0");

            const myquery = { "_id": id };
            
            const newvalues = { $set: { "name": "Marlon Brando" }};

            try {
                dbo.collection("plants").updateOne(myquery, newvalues, (err, res) => {
                    if (err) console.log(err);
                    console.log("update result", res.result, res.upsertedId);

                    db.close();

                })
            }
            catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
            
        }) 
        
    }
}

// test

const plant = new Plant("Alexa");
plant.updateMyPlant();
plant.getAll();

module.exports = Plant;

/**
 * Logs:
 * Mongo connected...
     update result {
         n: 1,
         nModified: 1,
         ok: 1
     }
 null
     [{
         _id: 5 fd8a1100617b03d8c737da0,
         name: 'Marlon Mickey',
         scientific_name: 'Brittain'
     }]
 */
```

As you can see the _id is retained while the properties you want to change are updated.

See more info about [ObjectID here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/#examples)